# A question about the dimension of the linear space of an n x n symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

**What I understand**

So there are many ways to describe an n x n symmetric matrix, you can describe it in a way such that all of the values are 0

$DION =\left | \matrix{ 0 & 0 & 0 & . . . . &0 \\ 0 & 0  & 0 & .. ..& 0 \\ . &. &.&.... & .\\ . &. &.&.... & .\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & . . . . &0 } \right |$

You can coincidentally also define a symmetric matrix in such a way that all of the Diagonal values are the only elements IN the matrix DION.

$ALEX =\left | \matrix{n & 0 & 0 & . . . & 0 \\ 0 & n + 1& 0 & . . . & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &n+2 & . ..  & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & .  & . . .& 0
\\  &  & & .& \\ & & & &n +n } \right|$
As no matter what you do with THIS matrix, $ALEX^T = ALEX$

Also, a matrix A is diagonal $iff$ $A\vec{v_n} = \lambda_n\vec{v_n}$ for some scalars $\lambda_1. . .\lambda_n$

So with that in mind, we can also describe a symmetric matrix as  :

$A = \left | \matrix{\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & . . . & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2& 0 & . . . & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &\lambda_3 & . ..  & 0
\\ 0 & 0 & .  & . . .& 0
\\  &  & & .& \\ & & & &\lambda_n } \right|$

**Where I fall short**

So, let's say that for all intents and puproses I need to find $dim(A)$

Well, I can already tell that $dim(DION)$ for $DION$ is different than $\space dim(ALEX)\space ||\space dim(A)\space$ for $ALEX$ or $A$, so that's telling me that $DION$ isn't considered symmetric.

Furthermore, how does one calculate the dimension of an n x n matrix if you only have a diagonal set of diagonal scalars of size $n$?

**What I think the answer is**

I think that $dim(A)= n$ *(we're going to use A because it's prettier)*
I think that it is n because if we have an n x n matrix, and a dimension is basically just a count of the amount of elements in a reduced matrix that need not be augmented. If the diagonal line is of size n, it would be about the size of a column or the size of a row, but not necessarily the size of a column times a row, right?

Comment: What does $\dim(A)$ even mean? And you're discussing symmetric matrices but writing down only diagonal ones.

Comment: Ted, aren't diagonal matrices symmetric? Also, $dim(A)$ is shorthand for dimension of matrix A. . . .

Comment: Of course. But the diagonal $n\times n$ matrices form a vector space of dimension $n$ and the symmetric $n\times n$ matrices form a vector space of dimension $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: They form n(n+1)/2 ? . . . Hmmm wait. . . I can think of another symmetric matrix $\left | \matrix {2 & 4 \\ 4 & 3} \right |$ So basically what I'm hearing is a diagonal matrix is a type of symmetric matrix that forms a dimension of n. But not all symmetric matrices are diagonal, right?

Comment: But why does a symmetric $n x n$ non diagonal form a vector space of dimension $n(n+1)/2$ ?

Comment: The diagonal ones are included among those symmetric matrices. Count how many degrees of freedom you have to fill in entries.